# What does single exclamation mark mean for bash history event designator?

Tags: linux, bash

I have just read about [Event Designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators) in bash documentation, but `!:gs/foo/bar` also works, should it be `!!:gs/foo/bar`? The docs say

> `!` Start a history substitution

so this also meaning the last command line is referred? Or here `!` is just an edge case for `!string` in `!:gs/foo/bar` when `string` is empty? FYI `^old^new` is equivalent to `!!:s/old/new/`, 
`^old` is equivalent to `!!:s/old//`.

Comment: @derHugo I run each command in different bash terminal sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the [section about Word Designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Designators), the manual says

> If a word designator is supplied without an event specification, the previous command is used as the event.

This means that if you use just `!` and a designator such as `:2`, the `!:2` will be interpreted as `!!:2`. Word designators are optional, so if you use only a modifier (as in your `!:gs/foo/bar` example), the same applies: the expansion applies to the previous command.

Comment: OK, this explanation is reasonable: (empty) word designator would use the previous command as the event if no event specified by any means such as `!!`, `!n` or `!-n` etc.